# App request is showing up on Facebook Notifications but NOT on the "Facebook Mobile App"

Tags: facebook, mobile, notifications, request, facebook-javascript-sdk

App request is showing up on Facebook Notifications but NOT on the "Facebook Mobile App".

The request is shown as it should on the facebook.com website, and a click on the request works perfectly.

Having said all that the Facebook mobile app, on our android and iPhone is not displaying the app request in the notification popup.

We generate the request through the js sdk, like so: (I've changed the actual values)

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'This is the request text',
  to: 123123123,1231231231,123123123,
  data: {
    uuid: 420,
  }
  }, function(response) {
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook requests not received](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13516395/facebook-requests-not-received) (same answer, but also including android login settings)